# Don't have permission for SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote an onEdit script that takes values from one spreadsheet and sets them in another.
I have used SpreadsheetApp.openById on other onOpen scrips without any issues.
But only for this specific new script it tells me I don't have the permissions to use openById.
I read other answers that said to change the oauthScopes an I did, but it still says I don't have permition.

```
{
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
      
],
  "timeZone": "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

This is the script I wrote.

```
function onEdit(e){

//reemplazar targetID por ID de hoja real
var targetID = '14VgIUDG7m0-Z9SGCec5GBfaivrA_8bakUTu2qfWw_Ho';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID);
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Cortes'); 

const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const SHEET_NAME = 'Pendientes';

const DATE_COLUMN = 4;
const FIXEDROW = 2;
const ESTADO_COLUMN = 5;
const ESTADO_COLUMN_2 = 25;
const RESP_COLUMN = 3;
const TARGET_ROW_COLUMN = 26;

const ESTADO = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, ESTADO_COLUMN).getValue();
const ESTADO_2 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, ESTADO_COLUMN_2).getValue();
const RESP = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, RESP_COLUMN).getValue();

Logger.log(row);
Logger.log(TARGET_ROW_COLUMN);

const TARGET_ROW = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, TARGET_ROW_COLUMN).getValue();
const TARGET_RESP_COLUMN = 3;
const TARGET_ESTADO_COLUMN = 5;
const TARGET_TIME_COLUMN = 4;


var cellRange = s.getRange(TARGET_ROW, targetColumn);

//set estado y resp
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == SHEET_NAME && row > FIXEDROW){
    //si modifica el estado
    if (ESTADO !== '' && ESTADO !== ESTADO_2) {
      var targetColumn = TARGET_ESTADO_COLUMN;
      var targetValue = ESTADO;
    }

    //si modifica el responsable
    else if (RESP !== ''){
      var targetColumn = TARGET_RESP_COLUMN;
      var targetValue = RESP;
    }

  cellRange.setValue(targetValue);

}

//set timestamp if estado=preparado o estado=entregado y resp<>"" y timestamp=""
//actualizar si cambian los nombres de los pasos de preparación
if ((ESTADO == 'Preparado' || ESTADO == 'Entregado') && RESP !== ''){
  var targetColumn = TARGET_TIME_COLUMN;
  var targetValue = new Date();

  cellRange.setValue(targetValue);
  
}

}
```

This is the spreadsheet where the script is posted, from where i source the values:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bo6mgrn4LBCU6wHvTVsaCkHxKc-q7oS7JOnN7AqLH7U/edit?usp=sharing

This is the target spreadsheet where the values must be copies (the one I reference with openByID):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14VgIUDG7m0-Z9SGCec5GBfaivrA_8bakUTu2qfWw_Ho/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

#### I believe you can do it with an installable onEdit trigger

Just as an example I copied data from one spreadsheet to another with this code

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.testsourceid);//this is just a global object that holds one of my spreadsheet ids
  const tsh = tss.getSheetByName("Sheet5");
  tsh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

The I just edited one of the cells on the source side and the data transfered immediately.  So just create an installable trigger but don't name it onEdit().  It will stilll work the same as an onEdit and even have the same event object.

Here's a copy of the event object:

```
{"authMode":"FULL","range":{"columnEnd":13,"columnStart":13,"rowEnd":23,"rowStart":23},"source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"value":"dd"}
```

Comment: Very cool. I'm keeping my answer up because it is technically correct that an onEdit cannot do this, but yours is a great workaround.

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is not possible using the OnEdit event.

`onEdit()` is [Contianier Bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) with authMode of `LIMITED` which is the same as including `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/` at top of script code. Stated differently, you cannot use `onEdit` to do anything outside of the spreadsheet that it's being called from. Your line of code `SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID);` will not work it is attempting to access a different spreadsheet.

### Workaround

While I didn't look too carefully at your code, I would bet you can do what you want if you used ImportRange. Just put this formula on a different sheet in your sheet, and then just use lookup functions:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("14VgIUDG7m0-Z9SGCec5GBfaivrA_8bakUTu2qfWw_Ho","'Cortes'!A:AB")
```

**Google's Documentation:**

A script is bound to a Google Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms file if it was created from that document rather than as a standalone script. The file that a bound script is attached to is called a "container." Bound scripts generally behave like standalone scripts except that they do not appear in Google Drive, they cannot be detached from the file they are bound to, and they gain a few special privileges over the parent file.

Note that scripts can also be bound to Google Sites, but these scripts are almost always deployed as web apps. Scripts bound to Sheets, Docs, Slides, or Forms can also become web apps, although this is uncommon.

[image]

Comment: Import range doesn't so what i want it to do, I need a script to get the values from one sheet and set them as values on the other one. Import range is a completely different thing, you cant edit the cells it populates and doesn't allow for two-way edit. But thanks for the info on onEdit fuctions, I worked around it by creating a custom function, which I then called on the onEdit.

Comment: You're sure calling the additional function works? I'm surprised it's so easy to get around the `Container Bound` limitation.

Comment: Yes, the code is already in use and is working.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by working around the onEdit limitations.
Instead of using SpreadsheetApp.openById directly on the onEdit, I created a custom function, which I then called on the onEdit.

```
function onEdit(e){ 

const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const SHEET_NAME = 'Pendientes';

const DATE_COLUMN = 4;
const FIXEDROW = 2;
const ESTADO_COLUMN = 5;
const ESTADO_COLUMN_2 = 25;
const RESP_COLUMN = 3;
const TARGET_ROW_COLUMN = 26;

const ESTADO = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,     ESTADO_COLUMN).getValue();
const ESTADO_2 = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,     ESTADO_COLUMN_2).getValue();
const RESP = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,     RESP_COLUMN).getValue();

Logger.log(row);
Logger.log(TARGET_ROW_COLUMN);

const TARGET_ROW = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,     TARGET_ROW_COLUMN).getValue();
const TARGET_RESP_COLUMN = 3;
const TARGET_ESTADO_COLUMN = 5;
const TARGET_TIME_COLUMN = 4;

//set estado y resp
if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == SHEET_NAME && row > FIXEDROW){
    //si modifica el estado
    if (ESTADO !== '' && ESTADO !== ESTADO_2) {
      var targetColumn = TARGET_ESTADO_COLUMN;
      var targetValue = ESTADO;
    }

    //si modifica el responsable
    else if (RESP !== ''){
      var targetColumn = TARGET_RESP_COLUMN;
      var targetValue = RESP;
    }

  exportValue(TARGET_ROW, targetColumn,targetValue)

}

//set timestamp if estado=preparado o estado=entregado y resp<>"" y     timestamp=""
//actualizar si cambian los nombres de los pasos de preparación
if ((ESTADO == 'Preparado' || ESTADO == 'Entregado') && RESP !== ''){
  var targetColumn = TARGET_TIME_COLUMN;
  var targetValue = new Date();

  exportValue(TARGET_ROW, targetColumn,targetValue)
  
}

}


function exportValue(row,column,value) {
  
  //reemplazar targetID por ID de hoja real
  var targetID = '14VgIUDG7m0-Z9SGCec5GBfaivrA_8bakUTu2qfWw_Ho';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Cortes'); 
  var target = s.getRange(row, column);
  
  target.setValue(value);
}
```